# Randomize XML with xsltproc

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple xml file:

```
<headlines>
  <headline>
  ...
  </headline>
  <headline>
  ...
  </headline>
  <headline>
  ...
  </headline>
</headlines>
```

All I want to do is shuffle the order in which headlines appear. I've been fooling around how this template should look, but I can't get it working.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/headline">
<xsl:for-each select="headline">
  __not sure what to do here? rand() isn't a thing?__
```

Comment: what's your xslt processor? java, c#, exslt, php?

Comment: Trying to accomplish from a bash script - I thought I could just call xsltproc. Is that not the case?

Comment: The accepted answer depends on the processor being libxslt. But if your processor **is** libxslt, then you have access to the EXSLT math:random() function - so it's not necessary to rely on the randomness of generate-id(). For a processor-independent method see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953336/randomize-node-order-xslt/21979885#21979885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use the function generate-id() as a sorting criterion. Suppose you have the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<headlines>
  <headline>
    Limburg
  </headline>
  <headline>
    Fukushima
  </headline>
  <headline>
    Große Koalition
  </headline>
  <headline>
    Flugzeugabsturz
  </headline>
</headlines>
```

With this XSLT you can "randomize" the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

  <xsl:template match="/headlines">
    <headlines>

      <xsl:for-each select="headline">
        <xsl:sort select="generate-id(.)"/>

        <headline id="{generate-id(.)}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="./text()"/>
        </headline>

      </xsl:for-each>

    </headlines>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<headlines><headline id="idm3928">
    Limburg
  </headline><headline id="idm5512">
    Flugzeugabsturz
  </headline><headline id="idm5704">
    Große Koalition
  </headline><headline id="idm5920">
    Fukushima
  </headline></headlines>
```

Three things should be noted:

- The output of attribute "id" in the headline tag is not necessary. This is just for visualizing the sort criterion.
- The sorting order depends on the xslt processor used (in this case a Debian xsltproc).
- It's not really "random". However, the processor xsltproc actually chooses new ids with every call so in fact the headlines get "shuffled". :-)

Comment: The EXSLT function `math:random` would be a better choice. Unfortunately, only very recent versions of `xsltproc` support the `--seed-rand` option which is essential for this task.

Comment: The `math:random` function would definitively be an alternative. However, my solution would have to be altered since using a random number as key in a sort may produce unpredictable results (in addition to the randomized output which, of course, is desired). One way to do this would be to create a temporary representation of the `<headline>`tags (e.g. by returning them from a template) and enhancing them with the random number. The calling template would sort the returned result according to the key then.

Comment: I know for sure that `libxslt` evaluates the expression for the sort key only once and other XSLT processors will probably do the same. So your solution could be used without structural changes.

Comment: Thanks - this is a great start. I At the moment it's spitting out <headline> but nothing in between, I suspect because there's other tags within, and we're only selecting text?

Comment: Please, replace the `"./text()"` by `"./*"`. That should do it.

Comment: This is NOT a good method. A processor is not required to randomize the generated ids at each call - or to randomize them at all. Using a Saxon engine, the input nodes will be "randomized" in a determined order (i.e. the same input will produce the same output every time). With a Xalan engine, the input order will not be changed at all - see: http://xsltransform.net/nbUY4kp

Comment: @michael.hor257k: It's a hack with limited scope. That's why I put some extra remarks into my answer when I gave it.